# When login request is split - the thread count is reduced

Tags: jmeter

The below request is a Login Use case which includes authentication and authorization.
[image]

Currently the login usecase has 10 url's
The last five urls are authorization and the first five url's is the authentication.

Since I need the response time of only Authentication I had to split the login part into 2.

1- When I dont split the login into 2 parts i.e authentication or authorization and when I run it as a Single request.

It goes upto 250 threads

2- When I split the login into 2 parts i.e authentication or authorization.

It only goes upto 200 threads.

Previously this issue did not occur as it went upto 250 threads when the request was split into 2.
No changes in the script

Answer (score 0):

Throughput shouldn't change no matter how do you "split" the requests, most probably you have a [Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) somewhere which [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) covers both parts afte the "split" which is being applied twice or something like this.

If you're not interested in "Authorization" metrics - just disable or remove the associated requests. Alternative option would be using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to remove the "Authorization" samples from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)